# Outlook add to internal link in email "file:///"

Tags: outlook, hyperlink, microsoft365

Since a week ago outlook chnaged his behaviour and started to add to the link used for the locall network  "file://" and made impossible to open local files, someone has a solution?

i tried to find a solution in the options but i didn't found anything

Comment: I'd suggest posting non-programming questions to the https://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Comment: yep maybe is better